# How the top bar hidden in android lollipop?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I need to put the top bar outside the " Drawer navigation" .

[image]

In my kitkat device , it looks good . but when tested at lollipop that bar appears .

Do not know how to remove it , I tried to change the subject of the activity to " NoActionBar " and similar themas . but it does not work .

Thank you.

I'm doing this design . the kitkat looks good .

lolipop but if you see that bar.
[image]

This is my main activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.like.mail.network.aupa.maillike.TestActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/top_toolbar" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_test" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my content_test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#222"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:listSelector="#D84B20">
        </ExpandableListView>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeWithoutActionBarTitle">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is my style:

```
 <style name="AppThemeWithoutActionBarTitle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="honeycomb">
        @style/ActionBarWithoutTitle
    </item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarWithoutTitle" parent="@style/ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions" tools:targetApi="honeycomb">useLogo</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set it Fullscreen mode ?

Comment: Yes. Full screen looks good. but when the screen is handled out bar phone ( which shows the stack , notifications, etc ) and cover some elements of my " top bar " .

and also I would like to have it good in normal mode. Is there sulicion for this problem?

Am I wrong structuring my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".TestActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeWithoutActionBarTitle">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In **res/values-v21/style.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="AppThemeWithoutActionBarTitle" parent="Base.MyTheme"></style>

<style name="Base.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: With that achievement hide the bar. but when the screen is handled the top bar of the phone (where the battery , notifications, etc ) , is mounted on some elements of my app .

Comment: @VipPunkJoshersDroopy try this new solution. Add stryle.xml into values-v21 folder.

Comment: I´m trying.. 

excuse me, I 'm new .

that style also should put it in the " style.xml " .

Aside from style to add that "values ​​-21 " I delete you have in " values" and put that too?

Comment: Any thoughts that the only change was the color of the bar.  

There is no way to assign a halt to 0 or something?

parent="Base.MyTheme"

which is " Base.MyTheme " explicitly should go well ?

or should replace ahy ?

Answer (score 0):

Accomplish move the bar with the following code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
```

Also remove the attribute: **android: fitsSystemWindows = "true"** of all the "layout including" and place it in the main.